# Why my SnappyData cluster faced with slow query about once a day

Tags: database, apache-spark, snappydata

When my cluster runs for a certain time(maybe a day, maybe two days), some queries may become very slow, about 2~10min to finish, when this happens, I need to restart the whole cluster, and the query become normal, but after some time, very slow queries happen again

Answer (score 0):

The query response time depends on multiple factor including
1. Table size, if table size grows with time then response time will also increase
2. If it is open source version then time spent in GC pauses, which in turn will depend on number of objects/grabage present in the JVM Heap
3. Number of Concurrent queries being run
4. Amount of data overflown to disk

You will need to describe in detail your usage pattern of snappydata. Only then It would be possible to characterise the issue.

Some of the questions that should be answered are like
1. What is cluster size?
2. What are the table sizes?
3. Are writes happening continuously on the tables or only queries are getting executed?

You can engage us at slack channel to provide us informations related to your clusters.